# Error in code of Binary Search in java

Tags: java, binary-search

I am doing  binary search in java.I want the array and the key values as user input so I am using scanner here.

> I have written this code but cannot understand why it doesn't work when I give the key value as user input.I know what is binary search and have gone through the other questions already on Stack Overflow,but mine is a coding problem which I cannot figure out so if anyone could help.My code is:

```
//Program for getting a key value doing Binary Search
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bin_Search{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
        a[i]= scan.nextInt();
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("Enter the value you want to find");
    int key = scan.nextInt();
    Bin_Search bin = new Bin_Search();
    System.out.println("position is" + bin.b_search(a,key));
}

//Method to perform binary search
public int b_search(int arr[], int key)
{
    int n = arr.length-1;
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = n-1;
    int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    while(lo<=hi)
    {
        if(a[mid]>key)
            hi = mid-1;
        else if(a[mid]<key)
            lo = mid+1;
        else 
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an IDE? Most of them are free - try one, then learn how to use debugger in that IDE, and you will never have to ask such a question again. The most popular IDEs are: IntelliJ IDEA (my choice), Eclipse, NetBeans.

Comment: Please give example of input, what output you expect and what output you get. “Doesn’t work” is so vague to me.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken, but it appears that your array is not necessarily sorted, which means that binary search will not necessarily work. Binary search requires sorted data.

Comment: Ok..I got my mistake.thanks bdw..:)

Comment: @michaelbmorris..Yes that's why I am using user-input array in which I will provide the array in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never change `mid`, you will check the same position in the array in infinite loop. You need to change it every iteration of the loop

```
while(lo<=hi)
{
    if(a[mid]>key)
        hi = mid-1;
    else if(a[mid]<key)
        lo = mid+1;
    else 
        return mid;

    mid = (lo+hi)/2;
}
```

By the way, you are missing the last item in the array

```
int n = arr.Length - 1;
int hi = n - 1;
```

Means `hi` is actually `arr.Length - 2`. Just do

```
int hi = arr.Length - 1;
```

Comment: Do you understand that your answer delayed the moment when author will learn the debugger at least for another week? And that next time when something won't work he will come here again, instead of doing the job by himself.

Comment: hey user3707125, First of all I am not using IDE and yes I don't know how to use the debugger ok. Now the main thing is that this site is for helping new programmers like me by good programmers like you.So bdw thanks..:)

Comment: and Thanks Guy for the solution..:)

Comment: @RahulSingh: _"this site is for helping new programmers like me"_ Not particularly, no. It is a Q&A, not a helpdesk. You are expected to do your own learning first and foremost.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet..Thanks for opening my eyes..:D and yes I have done my learning.It may be that the question I asked will be easy for you that's why I said so.

Comment: @RahulSingh: As suggested in other comments, please learn how to perform basic debugging before asking further questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Guy: Please do not enable these questions. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah..okayzz..I will.:)